# Cannot make new host in MAMP Pro 4 because Create button is always disabled

Tags: mamp

When I launch MAMP Pro and navigate to the Hosts tab, click on the "+" at the bottom of the list of hosts, the modal has the create button disabled and I cannot complete making a new host.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It seems that a new host must have a folder to contain it. EXAMPLE: username > Sites > ProjectName > ProjectName.dev

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the reason behind of all of this is because of this character "`-`" and this `_`.

Do not use this characters in your localhost name.